# Change Tab Bar View's button colour without Tab Bar Controller in Swift

Tags: swift, ios8, uitabbar

I am using Tab Bar to navigate from one view another view. In my screen shot, last button is highlighted. If, I click **Click me** button, **Favorites** button color should be highlighted to red. But, I couldn do that. If I use Tab Bar Controller, I can do this with, **tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1**. How can I do this without tabBarController in swift? Kindly guide me.

[image]

Comment: can u paste your code or more details

Comment: Hi Gajendra!!  No Code I am havin....!! I button action,, How can we do that?